# why the same java httpclient code return different results under different platforms--- linux and windows?

Tags: java, linux, apache, httpclient, web-crawler

When I run the same code under windows and linux,I get different results! In other word, it works well in windows, while it failed in linux! Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

The web page is I want to fetch is "http://www.linkedin.com/pub/song-xuemeng/4b/683/565".

the code is listed as follows:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.commons.httpclient.DefaultHttpMethodRetryHandler;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.cookie.CookiePolicy;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.params.HttpMethodParams;

public class api {
public String fetchAPI(String url) {
    GetMethod getMethod;
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    int statusCode;
    getMethod = new GetMethod(url);
    getMethod.getParams().setParameter(HttpMethodParams.RETRY_HANDLER,
            new DefaultHttpMethodRetryHandler());
    getMethod.getParams().setParameter("http.protocol.cookie-policy",
            CookiePolicy.BROWSER_COMPATIBILITY);
    getMethod.getParams().setParameter(HttpMethodParams.SO_TIMEOUT, 5000);

    BufferedReader reader = null;
    String result = "";
    String line = "";
    try {
        statusCode = client.executeMethod(getMethod);
        if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            System.err.println("Method failed: "
                    + getMethod.getStatusLine());
        }
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                getMethod.getResponseBodyAsStream(), "utf-8"));
        if (reader != null) {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // System.out.println(line);
                result += line;
            }
            reader.close();
            getMethod.releaseConnection();
            return result;
        } else{
            reader.close();
            getMethod.releaseConnection();
            return "";
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        getMethod.releaseConnection();
        System.out.println("opsss");
        return "";
    }
}

public static void main(String[] arg){
System.out.println(fetchAPI("http://www.linkedin.com/pub/song-xuemeng/4b/683/565"));
}


}
```

Comment: What kind of failure? If it is exception please post stack trace.

Comment: There are lots of *possible* reasons, including many that have nothing to do with differences between Linux and Windows.  You will need to provide us with more information if you want us to help you.

Comment: You should not use Commons HttpClient (which is no more supported), but instead use HttpComponents HttpClient: https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/index.html

Comment: And this code doesn't even compile, you make a call to `fetchAPI()` (which is not `static`) from `main()` (which is `static`).

Comment: And your `else` is dead code (`reader` will never be `null`, you affect it just the line before). And once I make the code compile, it correctly fetches the content of the page.

Comment: Define 'I get different results' and 'it fails'.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It seems to be the problem of linkedin with amazon ec2.